# How to authenticate sharepoint users against external site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint

We have recently deployed a bespoke asp.net mvc solution using the built in membership system to a client.
They now wish to build a SharePoint system to sit alongside this but would like all user management to take place in the mvc app.

Is this possible and if so, what would be the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can *technically* use SP with the SqlMembershipProvider (assuming that's what you used before with the "built in system").

SP has *no* user management capabilities for the SqlMembershipProvider, so I assume it'll be handled by your other app.

But SP sits atop the .Net membership providers, so you can configure it for SQL just like you would the ASP.Net webapp.